# Getting flat point cloud from disparity map

Tags: opencv, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, printer-control-language

I've been trying to generate a point cloud from a pair of rectified stereo images. I first obtained the disparity map using opencv's sgbm implementation. I then converted it to a point cloud using the following code,

```
[for (int u=0; u < left.rows; ++u)
                {
                        for (int v=0; v < left.cols; ++v)
                        {
                                if(disp.at<int>(u,v)==0)continue;
                                pcl::PointXYZRGB p;
                                p.x = v;
                                p.y = u;
                                p.z = (left_focalLength * baseLine * 0.01/ disp.at<int>(u,v));
                                std::cout << p.z << std::endl;
                                cv::Vec3b bgr(left.at<cv::Vec3b>(u,v));
                                p.b = bgr\[0\];
                                p.g = bgr\[1\];
                                p.r = bgr\[2\];
                                pc.push_back(p);
                        }
                }][1]
```

left is the left image, disp is the output disparity image in cv_16s.
Is my disparity to pcl conversion correct or is it a problem with the disparity values?

I've included a screenshot of the disparity map, point cloud and original left image.

Thank you!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPrdd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not confident with this language, but I noticed a thing: 

Assuming that this line convert disparty to depth (Z)

```
p.z = (left_focalLength * baseLine * 0.01/ disp.at<int>(u,v));
```

What is 0.01? If this calculation gives you a range of depths (Z) from 1 to 10, this factor reduces your range from 0.01 to 0.1. Depth is always close to zero and you have a flat image (flat image = constant depth).

PS I do not see in your code X,Y conversion from u,v pixel values with Z value. Something like

```
X = u*Z/f
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
The 0.01 is for converting the focal length and baseline values to cms. I used the opencv function calibrationMatrixValues which outputs those values in mm from the camera intrinsic matrix. However, I'm now using opencv's reprojectImageTo3D function to do the depth-disparity mapping and I'm getting 3D results but it's still severely lacking - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_2Iwz6JbA4pVi0tWVEyUFc1Tlk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @KarnikRam I thougth about another (maybe stupid) detail: did you know that sgbm algorithm provide a disparity value 16 times greater? (you have to divide by 16 to retrieve the real value)

Comment: Yes :) You can find my full code here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_2Iwz6JbA4pSHV0TVR2TG9INk0/view?usp=sharing ; you can ignore the LoadMetadata and LoadCalibration functions.

Comment: @KarnikRam I am not used to C++ but if these two lines are subsequential, `computeDisparity(left, right, disp);` `cv::reprojectImageTo3D(disp, xyz, Q, false, CV_32F);` where you divide disp by 16? (I see you scaled disp8 from 0 to 255 but it is another thing. You used disp in the 3d reconstruction).

Comment: Hi, I did use disp8 for computeDisparity too. No change.

Comment: @KarnikRam of course: disp8 is a scaled, not real value. `Disp8 = disp*255/(numdisparities*16)` , correct? My question was: where is the division by 16 in your code? Try something like `disp2 = disp/16`, then use disp2 to reproject. If that not work, the problem may be elsewhere

Comment: Hey, yes that was tried as well. Not much of a change in the output :/